# JOGL throwing ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: eclipse, macos, noclassdeffounderror, jogl, java-3d

I've seen this question brought up a couple of times on this website, but never really seen a clear answer, so excuse me from repeating it. While programming with JOGL and Java3D I've encountered some errors. I was trying to create a project that I might eventually put on the Android App Store. I began the project just using Java3D and JOGL and putting them in the system library on my mac, where they worked fine. Then to try to make the project portable I moved the J3D and JOGL files inside the project so they could be compiled into a jar file that would be runnable without needing to install j3d and JOGL. But then every time I ran the project it threw this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GL
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$PipelineCreator.run(Pipeline.java:73)
    at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline$PipelineCreator.run(Pipeline.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.Pipeline.createPipeline(Pipeline.java:90)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:832)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:274)
    at javax.media.j3d.GroupRetained.<init>(GroupRetained.java:155)
    at javax.media.j3d.TransformGroupRetained.<init>(TransformGroupRetained.java:116)
    at javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup.createRetained(TransformGroup.java:114)
    at javax.media.j3d.SceneGraphObject.<init>(SceneGraphObject.java:114)
    at javax.media.j3d.Node.<init>(Node.java:172)
    at javax.media.j3d.Group.<init>(Group.java:549)
    at javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup.<init>(TransformGroup.java:87)
    at src.Project.<clinit>(Project.java:47)
    at src.ProjectPanel.<clinit>(ProjectPanel.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GL
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

I'm using Eclipse as an IDE, and have the `jogl-all.jar` and `gluegen-rt.jar` files in the classpath of the project, as well as all of the require j3d jars, but it cannot find the `GL.class` file for some reason.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you export your application as a Runnable JAR use the 
         + Library handling:
           Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR
or
         + Library handling:
           Package required libraries into generated JAR

More information is available in the jogamp jogl wiki:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling

Also you will need to use the java **-jar** yourapp.jar command line option to run your application.

Comment: I hadn't exported it into a JAR file yet, but when I try doing what you said, it shows this:                                       `Catched URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 5: rsrc:, while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of null (null + gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /System/Library/Frameworks/gluegen-rt.Framework/gluegen-rt`

Comment: You will need to include the gluegen-rt-natives* and jogl-all-natives* into the eclipse project for all platforms you want to support in order to have eclipse include them with the exported project. This is mentioned in the Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE and JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling Also double check that you do not have any old versions of jogl and j3d inside the system folders, jogamp only recommend to deploy jogl and j3d with your application.

Comment: I have both of those files in the eclipse project classpath, right now for osx, and I will add the ones for other platforms once I get it working on osx

Comment: double check that you do not have any versions of gluegen jogl and j3d inside the system folders: /System/Library/Frameworks/gluegen-rt.Framework/gluegen-rt <-- this indicate you may still have a copy of gluegen-rt inside your system folder, remove it

Comment: Wow, thanks, I guess there were some java3d files left in my system library. I feel so dumb now thanks :)